# How can I conditionally include images in React Native Component?

Tags: image, reactjs, react-native

I am able to add static images to a `ListView` cell just fine (see code below), but how do I change the icon image dynamically?

From [React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html)

```
<Image source={require('./img/check.png')} />
```

is the recommended way to reference image files for both iOS and Android.

I have a component called `ExpandingCell` that has the option to show a bunch of different icons but everything else remains the same.

In a `ListView` I create a `cell` object and then pass it into the `ExpandingCell` to render

the ListView data source array looks like this:

```
var LIST_DATA = [
 ...
  {type: 'ExpandingCell', 
   icon: './CellIcons/MagnifyingGlassIcon.png', //unused
   title: 'Lorem Ipsum', 
   detail: 'Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.'},
...
];
```

then in `renderCell` method it gets passed the above cell object:

```
renderCell(cell) {
    if (cell.type === 'ExpandingCell') {
        return (
          <ExpandingCell cell={cell} />
        );
    }
}
```

Now in `ExpandingCell` I have this for `render()`:

```
render() {
    return (
        ...
        <Image source{
            require('./CellIcons/MagnifyingGlassIcon.png')
        }>
        </Image>
        ...
    );
}
```

However, when I try to make use of `this.props.cell.icon` like this:

```
<Image source={require(this.props.cell.icon)}></Image>
```

I get the following error: `Requiring unknown module "./CellIcons/MagnifyingGlassIcon.png".`

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The images have to be known during packaging. There's a section about it in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources).

Put this at the top of the file you define ExpandingCell in:

```
const MAGNIFYING_GLASS_ICON = require('./CellIcons/MagnifyingGlassIcon.png');
```

Then you can use the constant like this

```
let icon = someCondition ? MAGNIFYING_GLASS_ICON : SOME_OTHER_ICON;
<Image source={icon}/>
```

You have to have the requires for all images you want to use this way in there.

Comment: I read through eh docs more carefully, and I guess I was asking too much of the STATIC images haha. I like the `const` solution you proposed above, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

## How to conditionally display either "require" or "uri" images in React Native Component 2022?

```
/** Displays Conditional Image Mapped from API */
  const randomFunction= () =>
    allData.map((fetchedData) => (
      <View key={fetchedData._id} style={styles.data}>
        <Image
          resizeMode="cover"
          source={
            fetchedData.avatar === ""
              ? require("../../assets/img/stationsImage.jpg")
              : { uri: `${fetchedData.avatar}` }
          }
          style={styles.imageStyling}
        />
    </View>
    ));
```

Hopefully this gives a different solution on how to conditionally render images from either **require** or **uri** sources in react native mobile apps.