# React Native Adding images from data file

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native, listviewitem, react-native-listview

I have some static data like this:

```
{
    "title": "Book an Appointment",
    "image": "../img/icon_booking.png"
  },
  {
    "title": "Client Gallery",
    "image": "icon_gallery.png"
  },
  {
    "title": "Save Before/After Photos",
    "image": "icon_gallery.png"
  },
```

I am creating a list view and want to pass the relevant image into the list view cell. The listview is setup as follows:

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(data) => <MainListRow {...data} />}
/>
```

The MainListRow is seutp as follows:

```
const BOOKING_ICON = require('./img/icon_booking.png');

const MainListRow = (props) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {props.image ? <Image source={{uri: props.image}} style={styles.photo} /> : null}
    <Text style={styles.text}>
      {`${props.title}`}
    </Text>
  </View>
);

export default MainListRow;
```

I understand from other issues that the images need to be defined before calling them (example: [How can I conditionally include images in React Native Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899145/how-can-i-conditionally-include-images-in-react-native-component))

I cannot figure out how to get the uri for the image to work correctly, even for one image. Ideally I just want to pass the image in and have it work. I have tried different variations of the path to try and get it correct and matching the initial require but it makes no difference.

Comment: try to require images directly in your data file, like `"image": require("../img/icon_booking.png")` , and then use it like `<Image source={props.image} ... />`

Comment: @Cherniv - thank you, I thought it might just of been a certain way to do it, please submit as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment I was able to change my data structure and just require the image there:

```
var data = [
     {id: 1, text: 'row 1', image: require('./img/icon_booking.png')},
     {id: 2, text: 'row 2'},
     {id: 3, text: 'row 3'},
     {id: 4, text: 'row 4'},
     {id: 5, text: 'row 5'},
     {id: 6, text: 'row 6'},
     {id: 7, text: 'row 7'},
     {id: 8, text: 'row 8'},
     {id: 9, text: 'row 9'},
     {id: 10, text: 'row 10'},
    ];
```