# Conditionally Render Images in React Native

Tags: image, react-native

I have been trying to render an image based on a condition. Currently I have a list and it is empty at the start of the app, after a certain event, this list gets populated with a string, and the listLength variable changes from 0(false-ish) to 1(true-ish). I have tried passing both the list length and the list itself as a conditional for the image source using the ternary operator. Can someone please help me figure out what is going on.

```
  let connect_logs = []
  let connect_line_length = connectLogs.length

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image 
          source={
            connect_line_length ? require('../assets/images/connect_line.png') : 
                    require('../assets/images/no_line.png')
          }
          style={styles.lineImage}
        />
   )
```

Comment: Similar issue was mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899145/how-can-i-conditionally-include-images-in-react-native-component

Comment: I had actually come across that link and tried implementing the solution listed there as well, however, that did not work for me, it always ends up using the ternary fails condition and rendering the no_line image .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should keep in mind that (almost all the time) if you want to change the UI of your app (re-render a component) on the basis of some variable/object/list etc, then that variable/object/list etc. should be declared as a state variable.

So I would suggest you to initialize your list inside you component's state like this:

```js
state = {
  connect_logs: [],
}
```

Then whenever you want to add update your list you should perform this by calling `setState()` to re-render your UI to reflect the latest changes, for example:

```js
const updatedList = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']; //dummy values
this.setState({connect_logs: updatedList}); //update state to change UI
```

And now you should apply your condition on `this.state.connect_logs` to dynamically change the source of your image like this:

```js
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image 
          source={
            this.state.connect_logs.length>0 ?
                    require('../assets/images/connect_line.png') : 
                    require('../assets/images/no_line.png')
          }
          style={styles.lineImage}
        />
    </View>
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that the View tag does not have a close tag? I think this could not be the issue but just try closing the tag and also just for testing try this

```
    let connect_logs = []
    let connect_line_length = connectLogs.length

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image source={connect_line_length ? '1' : '0'}
           style={styles.lineImage} />
        </View>
    )
```